# Visual Basic: When Using Databindingsource how do I display the next unique Id in sequence

Tags: database, vb.net, data-binding

My problem is that I have been using databindings for my program. When I use addnew() it spawns a new set of data with the ID number of -1 and -2 and so on.

I want to be able to set the Id so that it will properly display the correct next ID in the sequence for an item in my database.

Comment: sorry, i'll edit the question

Comment: So, the Platform is WinForm and you're using a BindingSource? *When I use addnew()* on what? The ID of what? What is the relation with the database? You're not referring to the PK of a table, right? Can you post the code related to the *problem*?

Comment: That suggests that the data is from a database with an auto-generated ID field, probably Access with an `AutoNumber` column. If the database is auto-generating IDs then it doesn't make sense for you to specify them in the UI. Either let the IDs be completely auto-generated or not at all. Those negative numbers are to ensure no duplication of IDs already in the database and will/can be replaced by the final value after saving new data from the app to the database. Don't break a system that works for many thousands of developers the world over.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank You and sorry. I get it now. I'll keep that in mind .